# Use Iterator to get top k keywords

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, iterator

I am writing a Spark algorithm to get top k keywords for each country, now I already have a Dataframe containing all records and plan to do

```
df.repartition($"country_id").mapPartition()
```

to retrieve top k keywords but am confused on how I could write an iterator to get it.

If I am able to write a method or call native method, I can sort in each partition and get top k which seems not to be the correct approach if the input is an iterator.

Anyone has idea on it?

Comment: Can you put an example of the df?

Comment: Not convinced you need mapPartition for this

Comment: df is like country_id | keyword_name | search_freq, if we already repartitionBy country_id then we just need to sort search_freq in each partition to get top k keyword_name, does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using window functions, let's assume that column `_1` is your keyword and `_2` is keyword's count. In this case k = 2

```
scala> df.show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  2|
|  1|  4|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  0|
|  1| 10|
|  2|  5|
+---+---+

scala> df.select('*,row_number().over(Window.orderBy('_2.desc).partitionBy('_1)).as("rn")).where('rn < 3).show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| rn|
+---+---+---+
|  1| 10|  1|
|  1|  4|  2|
|  2|  5|  1|
|  2|  2|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I am thinking of using Window function but wondering whether mapPartition would have a better performance computational-wise?